# Get the first number in array.length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an dynamically created array. I'm trying to add a span tag that would say something like `1 of 20 items` then I can navigate through them.

So in the second `span` tag I have

```
$('.count_wrap--num').text(theData.length);
```

which gives me the total number in the array.
My first `span` tag, which I want to be at 1 looks like :

```
$('.count_wrap--numOf').text(theData.length);
```

However, it gives me the full number again, how can I get it so the first item is 1? I've tried `$('.count_wrap--numOf').text('1');` but the index starts at 0 so it counts up weird when navigating through

Comment: `it gives me the full number again` ... so you tried nothing actually

Answer (score 4):

Try using a counter. So each time they click the next button it will increment the counter and then display that counter in the html.

Javascript:

```
var counter=1;
$('#nextBtn').click(function() { counter++; });
$('.count_wrap--num').text(theData.length);
$('.count_wrap--numOf').text(counter);
```

Here is a fiddle of the example
https://jsfiddle.net/fawxngcL/1/

Comment: I currently have `myIndex = (myIndex + 1) % theData.length;` which works fine. I just can't figure out how to get my first index, when I load the page, to hit 1 and when I increment up to start at one rather then 0

Comment: @DevJuniorThe50421st for that you need a `counter` variable as suggested by Alex

Comment: Please check out the fiddle I made as an example